# UIPickerView get selected value without datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uipickerview

What would be the best way to get the value from a PickerView without having a datasource? So i can not read values from i.e. an array.

Current values are just row numbers, that i need to read after user is done with picking.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return 300
    } else {
        return 10
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return "\(row)."
    } else {
        return "\(row)"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:)`

```
let firstValue = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
let secondValue = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
```

Both will just be an `Int` value representing the currently selected row index in it's respective component. And since your values are starting from 0, you can use the values directly.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add this func:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(row)
}
```

Just take care that row starets at 0